# Regular Expression on how to find non-greedy domain name

Tags: regex

I have this text:

```
<img src = "http://yahoo.com/img.jpg"><img src="http://google.com/1.jpg"><img src="http://google.com/2.jpg">
```

I tried to use non greedy regex : `<img.*?google.*?>`

but i got the first match which is `<img src = "http://yahoo.com/img.jpg"><img src="http://google.com/1.jpg">` instead of only `<img src="http://google.com/1.jpg">` can I know how to do that???
Thanks

Comment: Which flavor of regex are you using? Python regex, JS...?

Comment: @FelipeSulser php, i tried it on regex101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex does not work because the first `.*?` matches this part of the text:

```
 src = "http://yahoo.com/img.jpg"><img src="http://
```

To fix it, you have to make sure that `img` and `google` are within the same tag. In other words, there should not be a `>` between them:

```
<img[^>]*google.*?>
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zOLl8o/1)